# Difficulty searching Kentico smart search index on integer field using API

Tags: asp.net, lucene, kentico

I have a Pages smart search index which uses the Standard analyzer. When I examine the generated index in Luke I can see that integer fields have a specific format. For example, all pages created by global administrator have the `documentcreatedbyuserid` field set to `10000000053`.

Reading the [documentation](https://docs.kentico.com/display/K8/Using+search+filters) I see that integer fields like this need to be searched using a particular syntax:

`+DocumentCreatedByUserID;(int)53;Administrator`

However, when I pass this string to the following code as the `searchQuery` variable I get no results.

```
        // Get search results
        var parameters = new SearchParameters()
        {
            AttachmentOrderBy = "",
            AttachmentWhere = "",
            CheckPermissions = false,
            ClassNames = null,
            CombineWithDefaultCulture = false,
            CurrentCulture = this.Context.CultureCode,
            DefaultCulture = CultureHelper.GetDefaultCultureCode(this.Context.SiteName),
            DisplayResults = resultsPerPage,
            NumberOfProcessedResults = 100,
            Path = startPath,
            SearchFor = searchQuery,
            SearchInAttachments = false,
            SearchIndexes = index,
            SearchSort = sort,
            StartingPosition = (page - 1) * resultsPerPage,
            User = this.Context.User.UserInfo
        };

        ds = CMS.Search.SearchHelper.Search(parameters);
```

This same code works fine for text field search queries. Can anyone explain:

1. Is there anything obvious I'm doing wrong?
2. What is the purpose of the final part of the `+DocumentCreatedByUserID;(int)53;Administrator` query. Why should I need to pass a text value here?

The field I actually want to search is a custom page type field called newstypeid, which I can see is storing its value in the same way in the index (e.g. a value of 34 is stored as 10000000034).

In Luke if I query `+newstypeid:10000000034` I get results. So maybe an easier solution is to find a way to translate an integer to this Lucene format? (i.e. 34 to 10000000034)

**UPDATE WITH SOLUTION**

Thanks to @richard-Šůstek for pointing me in the right direction. The following method will return a search clause in the required format:

```
    protected string GetIntegerIdClause(string field, int id)
    {
        var condition = string.Format("{0}:(int){1}", field, id).ToLower();

        return SearchSyntaxHelper.CombineSearchCondition(null, new SearchCondition(condition, SearchModeEnum.ExactPhrase, SearchOptionsEnum.NoneSearch));
    }
```

Comment: I have the exact same issue, but your solution isn't working for me. I still get no results from the API on any search on any of my int fields, even though the queries work in the Luke tool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should use **SearchValueConverter** class from the namespace **CMS.Search**. This class has static methods to convert specific data type values (int,datetime,etc.) to it's string representation for search terms construction.

Comment: Really helpful. You're quite right, this is a more elegant solution. Thank you so much.

Comment: Ah, nice method :)

Answer (score 1):

Can you try using something like this to transform the `searchQuery`?:

```
var condition = new SearchCondition(null, searchModeEnum, SearchOptionsEnum.FullSearch);

searchQuery = SearchSyntaxHelper.CombineSearchCondition(searchText, condition);
```

I noticed that Kentico is internally calling this method when passing the value from search text box to SearchParameters. I haven't had a chance to test this though. Maybe some other method in SearchSyntaxHelper would be useful too.

Comment: Thank you so much. Your advice helped me find the solution. See the edit to my OP for code that implements your suggested solution :)

Comment: Awesome, I'm happy it helped:) Was quite a wide guess since I can't test it at the moment.